# How to make dynamic dropdown for update form Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am interested in creating a dynamic dropdown on my form. For store.blade.php it's been successful. But for edit.blade.php, I don't know what to do. I can only set values ​​for the first dropdown column, while the second dropdown column, I can't.

Edit: How to display the values ​​for the idkelas column that have been stored in the Update Form?

**Blade**

Column1

```
<select name="idkamar" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Pilih kamar</option>
  @foreach ($kamar as $key=>$value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}"{{ ( $listkamar->idkamar == $key ) ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{ $value }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Column2

```
<select name="idkelas" class="form-control"></select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="idkamar"]').on('change', function() {
            var kamarID = $(this).val();
            if(kamarID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/kamar/ajax/'+kamarID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="idkelas"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="idkelas"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="idkelas"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>')
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function myformAjax($id)
    {
        $kelas = DB::table("kelas")
        ->where("idkamar",$id)
        ->pluck("name","id");
        return json_encode($kelas);
    }    
public function edit($id)
    {
        $listkamar = ListKamar::find($id);
        $kamar = DB::table("kamar")->pluck('name','id');

        return view('listkamar.edit',compact('listkamar','kamar'));
    }
```

Comment: What is returning in `data` inside `success` method? Do the `console.log` on it and see. Everything else seems correct to me, except for the `else` part.

Comment: What error it's throwing. Check console as well.

Comment: I cannot display the kelas column that has been saved. I'm sorry I forgot to explain this.

Comment: You just need to pass `$kelas` in `edit` action. And in the view template, you will get all the values of that.

Comment: @Dhananjay Kyada OK. Thanks.... I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass `$kelas` in edit action. And in the view template, you will get all the values of that.

Comment: im stuck with the same problem. can you please show how to pass that??

Comment: @stoneshak provide me code and more details about your issue